# A nice css style for ajax autoComplete Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

I would really like to stay with my current implementation of auto-complete done via `ajax toolkit`, as it was relatively easy to implement it via C#.

I could see the jQuery autocomplete has a lot of styling themes, like in links below (rounded corners, well designed style, etc.)

- [Link1](http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/)
- [Link2](http://www.jensbits.com/demos/autocomplete/)

**How could I set a CssStyle like that on an `AjaxToolKit AutoComplete Extender` ?**

If there is someone that knows how to simply do it, or has a nice style ready to be used
or even a link, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

trying the first link from search you get this great tutorial on how to style

```
AjaxToolKit AutoComplete Extender
```

http://vijaysinghnegi.blogspot.com/2012/04/best-css-style-for-autocomplete.html

the reason why jquery make look so stylish is because they provide a default style to it

but whit   `AjaxToolKit AutoComplete Extender` you got to play with CSS to make it look the 
way you want

```
<style type="text/css">
    /*AutoComplete flyout */
    .completionList {
        border: solid 1px #444444;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 2px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .listItem {
        color: #1C1C1C;
    }

    .itemHighlighted {
        background-color: #ffc0c0;
    }
</style>

 CompletionListCssClass="completionList"
 CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted"
 CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem"
```

Comment: thanks @CT i would try it ...if i had a well established base..just to start from , it is by far a basic(skeleton) a tutorial of how to asociate the classes to  act on each CSS property of the extender eg  `CompletionListCssClass` + `CompletionListItemCssClass`....etc' , though not how to make a list item be like a little div rounded gradient or it does not set a default looks to start from as i am really bad designer ...i will take ages to apply a stylish result..thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [Meteor autocomplete extender](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete), which allows both free text and multiple autocomplete sources. Meteor's data model allows for fast multi-rule searching with custom rendered lists.

I used the CSS style from [jquery-sew](https://github.com/tactivos/jquery-sew). See their [demo here](http://jquery-sew.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) or the [CSS here](http://jquery-sew.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/demo.css).