# Autocompletebox not calling Webmethod and pop for not displaying properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use autocompletebox using ajaxToolkit autpcompleteExtender. I refer this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/ajax-autocompleteextender-sample.html .But now I am facing two problems.

1. Its working fine when I use webmethod on code behind but when I try to use it from seperate webservice file its not calling their webmethod. For this I set service path also but its not working. Please check the code

**.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Curriculam_Mapping.WebForm2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">   
<div>
   <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtClass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtClass" ServiceMethod="GetCountry" ServicePath="WebService1.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" >
   </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender> 
</div>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**.asmx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
namespace Curriculam_Mapping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
         [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
         [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
         public static List<string> GetClass(string prefixText)
         {
              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
              con.Open();
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Class_Id,Title from Mst_Class where Title like @Name+'%'", con);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              da.Fill(dt);
              List<string> ClassNames = new List<string>();
              for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  ClassNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
              }
              return ClassNames;
           }
         }
     }
```

2. When I use webmethod on code behind its work fine but popup not displaying properly.Its not attach to textbox control. Please check this image file

[image]

Please help me for solving this problem.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution, just remove static keyword from web-method and its working,I don't know its a proper way or not but its working for me.
thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

`but popup not displaying properly`

This could be it is not getting the proper `css` for the pop-up.
Here is a link which has more about that

1. http://vijaysinghnegi.blogspot.in/2012/04/best-css-style-for-autocomplete.html
2. http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/custom-css-style-for-ajax-autocomplete-extender-1115.aspx

Similar question on SO

1. [A nice css style for ajax autoComplete Extender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076947/a-nice-css-style-for-ajax-autocomplete-extender)

### Edit 1

Try to uncomment this line

```
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Basically this method will be called through script and you have not allowed it to be called by java-script or jQuery.

So your code should be follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
namespace Curriculam_Mapping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
         [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
         [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
         public static List<string> GetClass(string prefixText)
         {
              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
              con.Open();
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Class_Id,Title from Mst_Class where Title like @Name+'%'", con);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              da.Fill(dt);
              List<string> ClassNames = new List<string>();
              for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
              {
                  ClassNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
              }
              return ClassNames;
           }
         }
     }
```

Comment: hey thank you its perfect solution but 1st one problem still pending.

Comment: @Ganesh you should put service and relative html for that in your question.

Comment: @Shekhar Please check modified question.

Comment: @Shekhar It through an error "Duplicate 'System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService' attribute". I think its already declare in above line.

Comment: @Ganesh is it a wcf-service if yes then what binding are you using?

Comment: @Shekhar no its a web-service